# Lipschitz continuity of a function on convex sets

Tags: general-topology, lipschitz-functions

I have an open bounded convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ $A.$ Fix $x\in A,$ and consider the function $\phi:S^{n-1}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that, for all $e\in S^{n-1},$
$\phi(e)=\sup\{t\geq 0: x+te\in A\}.$
I have proved that this function is continuous, and that $\partial A=\{x+\phi(e)e: e\in S^{n-1}\}.$ I want to prove that $\phi$ is Lipschitz continuous, and I want to estimate the Lipschitz constant using the diameter of $A$ and the distance of $x$ from $\partial A.$

I have
$d(x,\partial A)=\inf_{y\in\partial A}{d(x,y)}=\inf_{e\in S^{n-1}}\phi(e),$ and $diam(A)=\sup_{x,y\in A}{d(x,y}).$ I think the Lipschitz constant depends on $\frac{d(x,\partial A)}{diam(A)}$ (maybe this is the Lipschitz constant?), but I’m stuck in proving this fact.

Comment: Is $d$ a norm induced metric?

Comment: d(x,y) is the Euclidean metric

Comment: So the distance on $S^{n-1}$ is the euclidean metric from $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Yes, the distance on $S^{n-1}$ is the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ (at least, I suppose, since in the text of the exercise nothing let me think it is not so)